# Iron-Router list of routes to redirect

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In Iron-Router, is it possible to have a list of routes that all redirect to the same route? For example, if a user messes up and enters /page/not-a-page instead of /page/valid-page, I'd like to redirect them to /pages rather than an bad url page.

Answer (score 0):

You may define a not found template in that scenario, using:

```
Router.configure({
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});
```

Your notfound template can be your pages template for instance

Comment: That would apply for all templates then. Is there a way to do this for just this one route? Something like a regex catch?

Comment: You can also define a notFoundTemplate for a single route. It will be based on if your data function returns null